# How can I find my shell version using a Linux command?

Tags: linux, shell

I would like to know about my shell version using a Linux command. I tried the following command, but it shows the type of the shell I am in.

Command:

```
echo $SHELL
```

Result:

```
/bin/bash
```

Comment: Notice that you could use some strange shell, even one which is not POSIX compliant (e.g. [fish](http://fishshell.com/) or [es](https://wryun.github.io/es-shell/)...). You should know what shell you are using. If it is `bash`, indeed try  `bash --version`. Or use your package management system (`dpkg -l bash` on Debian or Ubuntu)

Answer (score 67, accepted):

This will do it:

```
$SHELL --version
```

In my case, the output is:

```
zsh 5.0.2 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
```

Comment: Not all shells have a `--version` option, but more do than don't, so this is probably your best bet.

Comment: I have some quibbles about this; see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38240328/827263).

Comment: The shell you're in doesn't necessarily matches your `$SHELL` variable. Use `/proc/self/exe --version`.

Comment: This reflects your login shell -- not the currently running shell.

Answer (score 20):

It depends on whether you want to know the version of your default login shell, or the version of the shell you're currently running. They're not necessarily the same.

For your default login shell, as the accepted answer says, `$SHELL --version` is likely to work. Most (but not all) shells accept a `--version` option. (`dash` does not.) And this assumes that the value of `$SHELL` hasn't been changed (there can be valid reasons to do so).

For the shell you're currently running, if it happens to be `bash` you can type:

```
echo $BASH_VERSION
```

For `tcsh`:

```
echo $version
```

For `zsh`:

```
echo $ZSH_VERSION
echo $ZSH_PATCHLEVEL # shows more detailed information
```

For `ksh`:

```
echo $KSH_VERSION
```

For `fish`:

```
echo $version
```

Again, this assumes that the relevant variable hasn't been modified (there's rarely any non-malicious reason to change it).

Bash in particular has an array variable `$BASH_VERSINFO` that gives more information in a form that's easier to process programmatically. Printing `$BASH_VERSINFO` only prints the first element; to print all elements:

```
echo "${BASH_VERSINFO[@]}"
```

Comment: This is a better answer.

Comment: What about /bin/sh or /bin/dash? (On Debian, /bin/sh is symlinked to dash.

Comment: @HankB: `dash` doesn't seem to have a version command-line option or command.On Debian or Ubuntu, `dpkg -l dash` will tell you which version is installed, but not necessarily the version you're running.

Comment: `/bin/dash` on Debian Buster contains the string `6323dd0fe3ec5af388e4ea4217a1f0092961d2.debug` which looks like some sort of commit ID maybe.  This corresponds to Dash version  0.5.10.2-5.

Comment: @tripleee It looks like it could be, but the hex string is 2 characters shorter than a git commit id, and there's there's no such commit in https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/utils/dash/dash.git (or any commit whose id contains `6323dd0fe3ec5af388e4ea4217a1f0092961d2`). Ubuntu 20.04 has `2a16ad1517b3d714e7b3bdb5470b2c82eb25ff.debug`, same story.

Answer (score 9):

There is a case when your shell does not have a command line parameter to determine the version directly. This case is Bourne shell. For Bourne shell I would recommend to use a script: https://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/whatshell/whatshell.sh. The script is pretty small so that it is not a big trouble to review it and understand how it is working. I have tested this script inside different shells on Linux and Solaris and it always gave the shell version for me. 
Some examples:

Ubuntu 18.04

```
$ sh -c './whatshell.sh'
ash (Busybox 1.x)
$ bash -c './whatshell.sh'
bash 4.4.19(1)-release
```

CentOS 4

```
$sh -c './whatshell.sh'
bash 3.00.15(1)-release
```

Solaris 10

```
~> sh -c './whatshell.sh'
ksh88 Version (..-)11/16/88i (posix octal base)
~> bash -c './whatshell.sh'
bash 4.1.7(3)-release
~> csh -c './whatshell.sh' 
SVR4 Bourne shell (SunOS 5 variant)
```

AIX 6.1

```
~> sh -c './whatshell.sh'
ksh88 Version (..-)11/16/88f
~> bash -c './whatshell.sh'
bash 4.2.0(1)-release
```

This is also answers for the question [Bourne shell version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5143469/bourne-shell-version) which was marked as off topic.

Answer (score 1):

Just use command

echo $BASH_VERSION

It must give you the version of shell. BASH_VERSION is the environment variable which contains version of shell.

Comment: This is obviously only relevant if you are running Bash.

Comment: Run "ps -p $$" to determine which shell you're using (without the quotes)